# echo 'archives : ' . single_cat_title(); displays wrong output

Tags: php, echo, archive

My PHP code is giving the wrong output I require.

```
<h4>
<?php        
    if ( is_category() ) {
        echo 'archives : ' . single_cat_title();
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        echo single_tag_title() . ' : archives';
    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        the_post();
        echo 'Author archives : ' . get_the_author();
        rewind_posts();
    } elseif ( is_day() ) {
        echo 'Daily archives : ' . get_the_date();
    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
        echo 'Monthly archives : ' . get_the_date('F Y');
    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
        echo 'Yearly archives : ' . get_the_date('Y');
    } else {
        echo 'Archives:';
    }
?>
</h4>
```

Gives out business archives :, but desire it to be archives : business.

How do I fix this, please

Thanks 
Steven

Comment: I think your function single_cat_title() doesn't return a string, but echo's it

Comment: It doesn't look like the output you state is possible from the above logic but I'd suggest echoing something unique to each clause to see which is being executed first

Comment: its the is_category() being echoed. just don't know how to get the [echo archive:] first before the single_cat_title()

Comment: single_cat_title('archive : '); sorry got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
single_cat_title('archive : ');
```

I found my answer, thanks for your help.